# ldap_connect() function in php accepts any value and doesnt throw an error

Tags: php, ldap, ldapconnection

I am writing a php code to connect to my LDAP server.

```
$adServer = $ini['ldap'];
$ldap = ldap_connect($adServer) or die("Could not connect to {$adServer}");
```

The Value for `$adServer` I am fetching from a configuration file.

Looks like `ldap_connect()` is not throwing an error when I pass blank value or any other random value like "Hello".

I tried giving the below code to check if any error message was generated.

`echo ldap_error($ldap)`

It always says 'Success'.

Hence I am not able to authenticate if the connection was established or not to the LDAP Server and throw an appropriate error message.

In what situation does the 'die' get triggered for `ldap_connect()` function.
I would like to throw an appropriate error message to the end user if the Server Name provided in the configuration file is not working.

Note: I am using Version 5.6 for PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way to do authenticate instead of using die. 
After ldap connect, we would continue using ldap bind.  If the bind fails, then we can check for the ldap error.

```
$ldap = @ldap_connect($adServer);
$bind = @ldap_bind ($ldap, $ldaprdn, $password);
if (!$bind) {  // If Bind Failed then.
    if (ldap_errno ($ldap) == 49 {
        //Invalid Credentials
    } else {
    //LDAP Connection to LDAP Server Failed
    }
}
```

For a list of all the LDAP Error Number, you can check [here](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=LDAP_Error_Codes#gsc.tab=0)

Answer (score 3):

`ldap_connect()` always returns a resource when it can parse the provided parameter as a URL. The first time that resource is actually used (and therefore a connection is established and a possible failure can be detected) is when using `ldap_bind()`.

As `ldap_connect()` **almost always** returns a resource-handle (as described in http://php.net/ldap_connect) your construct with `die()` wouldn't do what you want. It will only work if the provided parameter can't be parsed as URL internally. so as long as you provide a string that **looks** like a servername or a URL, everything works.

I always check after an unsuccessfull `ldap_bind()` what happened exactly and then throw an Exception depending on the error returned by . Alternatively I sometimes check before using the `ldap_bind()` by opening (and just closing) a connection using f.i `fsockopen()`. If that connection can't be opened the ldap-connection won't work either.

The examples on the referred php-documentation are missleading and it seems we will have to change them. So thanks for spotting and throwing up the question!

BTW: calling `@ldap_connect('ldap:');` for instance would be such a case where the `die()` would work as it's an incomplete URL. Or using a string with whitespace.